# How to record generated jQuery form into xml file?

Tags: jquery, xml, jsp

I've managed to make some sort of form which generates exam by jquery. And now i want to publish it. I'm using jsp. Is it possible to record my generated exam form into an xml file, and read it from server when user wants to take that exam, it will look as an exam form? If it is, how can i do it? Can you give me some examples?

Thanks in advance,
Timur

Comment: well.. i make the exam generation part, if you would like to see it, of course i can give the code. but i think it's irrelevent for topic.

i'm asking for a way or key term something like api or plugin or link for an example etc. whatever will work :)

Comment: @SomeKittens , well.. any idea?? :)

Comment: It may be possible to send the data via AJAX to a `.php` file that will extract it to XML, but that's the best I've got.

Comment: hi, thanks for response. i aşso write the same question to jQuery's own forum. someone suggested jQuery.ajax() api too

Comment: If you want, I can write that up with more details as an answer.

Comment: That would be great. i will be appriciate to you.
I began jquery long time ago but before get through basics, i had to quit. :/
.
*ps: xml or json doesn't matter. all i need is to store my exam form in a data format

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the generated HTML by [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) in jQuery.

```js
var html = $("#idOfElementThatContainsGeneratedForm").html();
```

Then you need to send it as a request parameter to the server somehow. Perhaps by [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

```js
$.post("urlOfServletThatProcessesSubmit", { "html" : html });
```

Finally you can get it in the servlet as follows:

```java
String html = request.getParameter("html");
```

You can if necessary turn it into XML by a JAXP based HTML parser like JTidy and so on.

Answer (score 0):

1.) The first step will be to send the data from jQuery to a php file.  This can be done with [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).
2.) In the php file, you will need to assign the POSTed variables to "normal" variables using the following syntax: `$localvar = $_POST['nameOfPostedVar']`
3.) You then can perform file operations using php.  `$file = fopen('filename', 'w')` (it'll create the file if it doesn't exist, the w tells php to open the file for writing).  Write to the file using `fwrite($file, $stuffForWriting)`.  When you're done, make sure to `fclose($file)`.